# Normality of a lognormal variable having a spike in 0?

Tags: mean, outliers, lognormal-distribution, zero-inflation, t-distribution

I have two very right-skewed datasets which I must study for difference in means. Given the skewness, I transformed using log 10 scale after adding 1 to be able to take the log. In other words: `xx = log10(x+1)`.

`xx` is nicely normally distributed, which is good, but I have a neat spike at 0 (`x` is quite sparsed).

Since the $t$-test is very robust about normality, can I apply a inference test against means anyway? I don't think I can remove the zeroes as normality since the spike is quite high (around .2 times the expected value). Have I to consider these values as outliers?

Answer (score 6):

Let me try restating your situation.

1. You have very right skewed variables of interest, mostly positive but with marked spikes at zero, generically $x$.
2. To make the distributions easier to handle, you used the transformation log ($x + 1$). (The base of the logs, 10 or e or anything else, is immaterial here.)

I would not describe #1 as lognormal or #2 as normal. What's more, your reporting that a distribution is normal, except for a spike, would widely be considered contradictory, or at least puzzling. Many distributions could be described as normal, except in so far as they are not.

What to do about your "outliers" of 0 depends on the science of your problem. You must not discard them just because they are awkward for any method.

Your main question can be restated as whether you have moved sufficiently closer to normality to justify use of the $t$-test.

It is difficult to give precise advice, but here are some questions:

1. Why you are focusing on the means? Are there scientific reasons for being interested in the means of log ($x + 1$)? Or in the means of $x$? (Sometimes means make sense regardless of the distribution, because totals make sense.) If you are really interested in comparing the means of $x$, comparing the means of log ($x + 1$) is not the same question.
2. Sometimes people do $t$-tests as a matter of habit or ritual, but the real question is whether the distributions are the same. If that is so, a quantile-quantile plot is a better choice.
3. Much depends on your sample size. With a large sample size, normality assumptions bite less and in any case it may be that any test would yield a respectably low $P$-value.

One strategy is that you could try various different tests, on the untransformed and on the transformed values. They are not asking the same question, but if they gave loosely similar $P$-values you would have some basis for reporting means to be different, regardless of how means are defined. If they give very different results, you have some hard thinking to do.

Comment: To add to Nick's excellent answer, the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test should be considered, and the mean should be abandoned as a summary statistic for your problem.  Though widely believed, the $t$-test is not nearly as robust against normality as many think.  The proportional odds model is a generalization of the Wilcoxon test, which can nicely handle a spike in the data.

Comment: Two very good answers so far, but I think that we need to take a step back and that you need to tell us more about what is going on. What is X? Why is there a spike at 0? Does the data call for some model that incorporates two questions:  0 vs. any and then something among the any?

Comment: Tnx to all the good answers, I'm reading more times to understand better what's inside. About the meaning of X observations: each observation is the total amount of pageviews for a page in my website in a given month. My two datasets are built with the whole set of pages in my website, measuring pageviews in two distinct months (before and after a complete reworking on the site). So the zero means no visit on that page in that month. But the observations are not paired, as i changed not only the template but also the total number of pages (splitting and merging) and the permalink structure.

Comment: This seems to match my comment that means make sense because totals do.

Comment: The qqplot(x=X1, y=X2) shows a incredibly neat linear progression, except for a drop on the very left edge. I cannot estimate if this discontinuity is relevant, so I tried the Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test, as Frank adviced. The p-value against the null of both samples being from the same population is absurdly small (2e-16). Is this because of the very large sample size or is finally ok to say X1 and X2 are from the same population (ie. doing a t.test against the null mean(X1)=mean(x2) will going to fail to reject, regardless the normality/lognormality of X1 and X2?)

Comment: You haven't told us your sample size, but what you report sounds consistent with a very large sample size. Perhaps you don't need significance tests after all!

Comment: (typo in my last comment: it's going to *not* fail to reject, ofc). Sample size is ton if I consider the whole set of pages. Around 80k samples. But I'm going to slice the set of pages by category, obtaining many smaller sets.

Answer (score 3):

Nick Cox already gave some very good advice. I'll just make one additional comment:

There is no need to guess whether or not the $t$-test is robust enough for your data. If you change the data such that the means are the same but otherwise the distribution of the variable remains unchanged, then you can just use the bootstrap to simulate. The $p$-value should follow a continuous standard uniform distribution. In the example below (using Stata), with a fairly small sample size and fairly skewed variable, the $p$-values still seem to perform OK. This is obviously no guarantee that the $t$-test will also work for your data, and that is not the intention of this example. It is there to give you some code so that you can try it out on your data to see if the $t$-test works well enough for your data. You can also use this simulation to compute a bootstrap estimate of the $p$-value and the associated Monte Carlo confidence interval.

```
. // some data preparation
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. keep mpg foreign

. keep if !missing(mpg,foreign)
(0 observations deleted)

. 
. tempname omean tobs

. tempfile bsauto2

. 
. // compute the t-test on the data
. ttest mpg, by(foreign) unequal

Two-sample t test with unequal variances
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Group |     Obs        Mean    Std. Err.   Std. Dev.   [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
Domestic |      52    19.82692     .657777    4.743297    18.50638    21.14747
 Foreign |      22    24.77273     1.40951    6.611187    21.84149    27.70396
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
combined |      74     21.2973    .6725511    5.785503     19.9569    22.63769
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |           -4.945804    1.555438               -8.120053   -1.771556
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff = mean(Domestic) - mean(Foreign)                         t =  -3.1797
Ho: diff = 0                     Satterthwaite's degrees of freedom =  30.5463

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.0017         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0034          Pr(T > t) = 0.9983

. scalar `tobs' = r(t)

. 
. // create a "population" in which H0 is true but is
. // otherwise as similar as possible to the data
. summarize mpg, meanonly

. scalar `omean' = r(mean)

. summarize mpg if foreign==0, meanonly

. replace mpg = mpg - r(mean) + `omean' if foreign==0
mpg was int now float
(52 real changes made)

. summarize mpg if foreign==1, meanonly

. replace mpg = mpg - r(mean) + `omean' if foreign==1
(22 real changes made)

. 
. // compute the t-test on draws from the "population"
. // in which H0 is true and store the results
. set seed 1

. bootstrap p=r(p) t=r(t), rep(20000) strata(foreign) saving(`bsauto2') nodots: ///
>  ttest mpg, by(foreign) unequal

Warning:  Because ttest is not an estimation command or does not set e(sample), bootstrap has no
          way to determine which observations are used in calculating the statistics and so
          assumes that all observations are used.  This means that no observations will be
          excluded from the resampling because of missing values or other reasons.

          If the assumption is not true, press Break, save the data, and drop the observations
          that are to be excluded.  Be sure that the dataset in memory contains only the relevant
          data.

Bootstrap results

Number of strata   =         2                  Number of obs      =        74
                                                Replications       =     20000

      command:  ttest mpg, by(foreign) unequal
            p:  r(p)
            t:  r(t)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |   Observed   Bootstrap                         Normal-based
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           p |   .9999999   .2887153     3.46   0.001     .4341284    1.565871
           t |   1.75e-07    1.03631     0.00   1.000    -2.031129     2.03113
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. use `bsauto2', clear
(bootstrap: ttest)

. 
. // compute the bootstrap estimate of the p-value
. qui count if abs(t) >= abs(`tobs')

. di as txt "bootstrap estimate of the p-value: " ///
>    as result %6.4f (r(N) + 1) / (_N + 1)
bootstrap estimate of the p-value: 0.0041

. 
. // there is randomness involved in the way I computed
. // the p-value, so I would like to see a confidence interval
. local a = r(N) + 1

. local b = _N + 1 - r(N)

. 
. di as txt "95% MC CI: [" ///
>    as result %6.4f invibeta(`a', `b', .025) as txt ", " ///
>    as result %6.4f invibetatail(`a', `b', .025) as txt "]"
95% MC CI: [0.0033, 0.0050]

. 
. // see if the p-value behave as they should  
. simpplot p, overall reps(20000)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Peter Flom raises a very important question, one that needs to be addressed before any methodological strategy.  In fact, it is quite common that the 0s mean something by themselves.

For example, one can think of smoking where the continuous variable represent dosage, but where non-smokers will have a 0 value not because it represents a measured quantity, but because it represents lack of exposure.  Another example would be a measurement instrument where a measure is below a detectable levels.

In these cases it's often easier to include a dummy variable in the model representing presence/absence of characteristics together with the continuous variable (both have to be coded appropriately).  A good reference is:

Robertson C, Boyle P, Hsieh CC, Macfarlane GJ, Maisonneuve P (1994) Some statistical considerations in the analysis of case-control studies when the exposure variables are continuous measurements. Epidemiology 5 (2):164-170

and,

Leffondré K, Abrahamowicz M, Siemiatycki J, Rachet B (2002) Modeling Smoking History: A Comparison of Different Approaches. American Journal of Epidemiology 156 (9): 813–823